# android studio 3.5 image asset launcher icon (legacy only) shape none not working

Tags: android, shapes, android-studio-3.5, android-asset-studio

Just updated my android studio to 3.5 tried to import an image using asset studio.

Selected-

```
icon type : Launcher icons (Legacy only)

name : test_icon

asset type: image

path: path of image having transparent background

trim : no

background : #ffffff

scaling : crop

Shape : None (this is the problem ,it is supposed to show the transparent background image as it is but it still adding white background)

Effect : None
```

How can this be done?

Comment: my problem is that foreground layers will become scaled up when i install app

Comment: is the android studio bug or some configuration error?

Answer (score 1):

I actually faced this problem too, so I filed a report and they answered that this is not a bug and it's intentional. check out the issue here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140183584

Comment: any idea? how can we create an icon with a transparent background?

Comment: you can use vector asset or just copy the icon in drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

problem was with the **android studio 3.5**

just changed installed another version of **android studio `3.4`** and used the image asset creator of that one to create the application icon.

you don't have to uninstall android studio 3.5 just install 3.4 to use it for creating application icons

Comment: ya did that already bro...  was looking for any permanent solution ... thanks btw...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem without updating Android Studio:

1. You must copy `ic_launcher_background.xml` from drawable resource folder with a desired name such as `ic_launcher_background_transparent.xml`
   to a folder in your computer.
2. Open `ic_launcher_background_transparent.xml` in edit mode and add `android:tint="@android:color/transparent"` in the vector tag.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:width="108dp"
       android:height="108dp"
       android:viewportWidth="108"
       android:viewportHeight="108"
       android:tint="@android:color/transparent">
   ```
3. Then, right-click in project and go to `New` > `Image Asset` and select icon type as `Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)` and in the `Background Layer` Tab select the `ic_launcher_background_transparent.xml` file as path.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying 
I think you got the question wrong.
i don't want to create ic_launcher app logo icon i just want to import a normal image with transparent background to be used inside the app using Launcher icon (Legacy only)

Comment: I got your question. In android studio 3.5 you can not import image with transparent bg by Launcher icon section, but you can use of my solution and test it.